# Finding combinations of couples given a group of 6 men and 6 women

Tags: combinatorics

From a group of 6 men and 6 women:

a) How many different different-sex couples can be selected? How many same-sex ones?

b) This is a different question. You have to split up the group into different-sex couples so that everyone has a partner. In how many ways can this be achieved?

c) Now you have to split up the group into same-sex couples. In how many ways can this be achieved?

d) Now you have to split up the group into couples, same-sex or otherwise. In how many ways can this be achieved?

I was thinking $6!=720$ would be the total number of different-sex couples and $2\binom{6}{2} = 30$ same-sex couples for part a, but am unsure about the difference between what part a and parts b and c are asking.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I was thinking 6!=720 would be the total number of different-sex couples and 2*(6 choose 2)=30 same-sex couples for part a, but am unsure about the difference between what part a and parts b and c are asking.

Comment: When we ask, "How many different couples can be selected from this group," we are counting the number of ways that _one couple_ can be selected. When we name that one couple we know all we need to know about that selection. But if we want to split up a group into couples, each way to do it must make a list of couples; here we require 6 couples since we have 12 people to pair off. The restrictions concerning different-sex or same-sex couples reduce the number of ways the couples can be selected, but don't change the number of couples in each selection.

Answer (score 2):

a.) To pick a unique different sex couple you need to pick a man then pick a woman, use the product rule here.
    To pick a same sex couple you need to pick a subset of 2 people from the 6. Compute 6 choose 2 and then multiply by 2 to account for the fact that you can choose from both the men and women

b.) Pair them off by lining the men up and having them select women. The first man has 6 choices for women, the second has 5, the third 4, etc. until the final one is already matched.

c.) Consider only the men. The first man has 5 choices for a partner. The second man has 3 choices, the third has no choice. So there are 15 same sex couples in one group, and 15 for the women as well. Use the product rule to get all possible combos

d.) Aggregate them into a group of 12 people. Then pair off as before. The first person has 11 choices the second person has 9 choices, etc. so the total number of couples should be $11 \times 9 \times 7 \times ... \times 1$

Let me know if there are any mistakes here.

Comment: Apologies if this is obvious, but what is the product rule in this context?

Comment: six times six...